# disable auto-rotate in someone else's viewcontroller

Tags: ios, rotation

I'm using navigationController to push someone else's view controller. I can use shouldAutorotate to disable rotation in my view, but this doesn't work for the pushed view, which was implemented by someone else and I can not touch. Is there any way to achieve this? for example by disabling any rotation in any subview of my navigation controller?
Thanks!

Comment: Which iOS version are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push your own subclass of the vc, one that implements `supportedInterfaceOrientations` like this:

```
// .h
#import "ThirdPartyVC.h"
@interface  MyNonRotatingThirdPartyVC : ThirdPartyVC
@end

// .m
@implementation MyNonRotatingThirdPartyVC

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Allocate and present a MyNonRotatingThirdPartyVC instead of the original
.

Comment: Thanks danh! It works! I thought I could just use some category and don't have to subclass it...